# JSON format of result isn't correct

Tags: java, rest, badgerfish

I have developed RESTful web service which is running fine I have used one POJO and one service class that is shown below but the issue is that in the output it is showing extra $ please advise how to correct that right now the output is coming as

```
{
   "student":{
      "@id":"10",
      "age":{
         "$":"25"
      },
      "collegeName":{
         "$":"UP College"
      },
      "name":{
         "$":"Ram"
      }
   }
}
```

and I want that output should be

```
{
   "student":{
      "@id":"10",
      "age":25,
      "collegeName":"UP College",
      "name":"Ram"
   }
}
```

so below is my POJO

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement(name = "student")
public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String collegeName;
    private int age;

    @XmlAttribute
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getCollegeName() {
        return collegeName;
    }

    public void setCollegeName(String collegeName) {
        this.collegeName = collegeName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

below is my service class

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.jaxb.json.BadgerFish;


@Path("/restwb") 
public class StudentService {

    @BadgerFish
    @GET
    //@Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Student getStudentDetails(){
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setId(10);
        student.setName("Ram");
        student.setCollegeName("UP College");
        student.setAge(25);
        return student;
    }

}
```

and here is my `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.concretepage</groupId>
<artifactId>RestWB</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>      
</project>
```

Comment: why do you use Xml-Annotations if you want JSON?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the [documented behaviour](https://badgerfish.ning.com/) of Badgerfish:

> Text content of elements goes in the $ property of an object.

From the documentation, there's no obvious way of transforming to object properties that don't have an `@`. (If you're happy with `@age`, you could use an `XmlAttribute` for age instead of `XmlElement`.)

But as you don't seem to have any need for an XML representation anyway, I'd suggest moving away from Badgerfish for your JSON representation, as Badgerfish is explicitly meant to be a transform from XML documents to JSON documents.

Answer (score 1):

The format you get is what [Badgerfish](https://badgerfish.ning.com/) you gives. There is no way to change it. Either remove Badgerfish at all and get convenient JSON, or consume the result of this library's work.